# How can I fix puppet refusing to start and asking for "master.pp"?

Tags: linux, unix, configuration, deployment, puppet

I'm using the very latest version of `puppet` and have been following the Apress "Pro Puppet" guide step by step. I have installed `puppet`

```
sudo aptitude install ruby libshadow-ruby1.8
sudo aptitude install puppet puppetmaster facter
```

I have edited `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` to include certname

```
[master]
certname=puppet.mydomain.com
```

I have edited /etc/hosts and added the following line

```
127.0.0.1 puppet.mydomain.com puppet
```

I have set the hostname of the server

```
echo "puppet.mydomain.com" > /etc/hostname
hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

And then I try and run `puppet` from the command line.

```
puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize
```

And `puppet` gives me this error:

```
Could not parse for environment production:
Could not find file /master.pp
```

I'm running all commands with `sudo` and the last line of the error message always says that it can't find `master.pp` and the path before it is to my current working directory.

What am I doing wrong?

I should also mention that I don't have a DNS record set up for `puppet.mydomain.com` - I saw some online documentation mentioning this might be a problem - however I was fairly sure that the `hosts` file would let me get around that.

Comment: If you are on Debian/Ubuntu why wouldn't you just restart puppet?  You only added the certname and didn't removed the other settings from your puppet.conf right?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu - it never started the first time. Also if I set the certname then it won't start if I use `puppetmasterd` but if I remove the certname it will start using `puppetmasterd` but not with `puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize`

Comment: Post the full config of `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It almost seems like you're using an old version of Puppet, which doesn't understand the master subcommand, and tries to run it as a manifest instead. Somewhere around 0.25 the new command syntax was introduced.

Double-check which version you're running. The current version should be 2.7. I've often found that distros package older versions. For example, Ubuntu 10.04LTS installs 0.25.4, which is pretty ancient.

Comment: Very nice! It was installing `0.25.4-2ubuntu6.5` which is def. not the version I wanted. Thanks so much! Now I need to find the best way to get 2.7 installed. I am running Ubuntu 10.4 (LTS).

Comment: nm - found it here http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Puppet_Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

To find out the version of the puppet package, run:

```
sudo apt-cache policy puppet
```

Answer (score 1):

[Martijn](https://serverfault.com/users/9082/martijn-heemels) is [right](https://serverfault.com/questions/332580/how-can-i-fix-puppet-refusing-to-start-and-asking-for-master-pp/332605#332605). Your puppet version is definitely older than 2.6. Are you running an old version of Ubuntu or Debian? Squeeze already includes 2.6 and Ubuntu 11 includes 2.7. If you are on Lenny, you can find a newer version of Puppet on backports. And, if none of that helps, I think puppetlabs has a repository for newer puppet versions, though it might give you some trouble with ruby version.